# Regarding Nginx 1.22-stable source code building, how to enable all original include modules? especiallly for "ngx_http_log_module"

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

All, i downloaded the nginx-1.22.1.tar.gz from https://nginx.org/en/download.html, and was going to configure the http module of "ngx_http_log_module" for logging analysis purpose, but unfortunately, seems the module does NOT work as i expected.

the original included http modules in the source package are like below:

```
[root@centos-7-2 nginx-1.22.1]# ls -al src/http/modules/
total 1712
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001 1001   4096 Mar 12 20:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 1001 1001   4096 Mar 12 20:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  11866 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_access_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6994 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_addition_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  11742 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_auth_basic_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  11525 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_auth_request_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  31112 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_autoindex_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  19921 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_browser_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  41078 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_charset_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   8737 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_chunked_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  32273 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_dav_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6240 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_degradation_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   5536 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_empty_gif_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 113329 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6426 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_flv_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  22371 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_geoip_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  44070 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_geo_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 142741 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_grpc_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  17038 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_gunzip_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  29921 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_gzip_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   8468 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_gzip_static_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  21700 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_headers_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  42569 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_image_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  15036 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_index_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  20585 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_limit_conn_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  28816 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_limit_req_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  49773 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_log_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  15012 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_map_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  21205 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_memcached_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6794 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_mirror_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 118391 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_mp4_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6976 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 142075 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_proxy_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   8973 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_random_index_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  26701 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_range_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  15328 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_realip_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  17385 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_referer_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  28370 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_rewrite_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  61441 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_scgi_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   9205 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_secure_link_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  14029 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_slice_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6615 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_split_clients_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  79675 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   2800 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  39456 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_ssl_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   2105 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_ssl_module.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   8072 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_static_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   6094 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_stub_status_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  26018 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_sub_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  10833 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_try_files_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  18728 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_upstream_hash_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   7555 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  14923 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_upstream_keepalive_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   8198 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_upstream_least_conn_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  12803 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_upstream_random_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001   8644 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_upstream_zone_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  25004 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_userid_filter_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  75803 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_uwsgi_module.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  29999 Oct 19 16:02 ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.c
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 1001    126 Mar 12 20:24 perl
```

but when i was trying to build the nginx package, then run nginx -V to check the installed modules, seems no any module was loaded :

```
[root@centos-7-2 nginx-1.22.1]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx
checking for OS
 + Linux 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found
 + using GNU C compiler
 + gcc version: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) 

........................
.............
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
    -o objs/ngx_modules.o \
    objs/ngx_modules.c
cc -o objs/nginx \
objs/src/core/nginx.o \
.....................
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_zone_module.o \
objs/ngx_modules.o \
-ldl -lpthread -lcrypt -lpcre -lz \
-Wl,-E
sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/usr/local/nginx|" \
    -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid|" \
    -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf|" \
    -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log|" \
    < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/nginx-1.22.1'
```

```
# make&make install
make -f objs/Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/nginx-1.22.1'
test -d '/usr/local/nginx' || mkdir -p '/usr/local/nginx'
..................
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/nginx-1.22.1'
[root@centos-7-2 nginx-1.22.1]#
```

```
# ./nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.22.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) 
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/nginx
```

really not sure how to use the original included http modules, the expected http module i want to use is ngx_http_log_module.c, according to the official instruction on page of https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_session_log_module.html, the below directives can NOT be used successfully:

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            session_log one;
        }
.......

# ./nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "session_log" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:47
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

By the way, i have also tried to use the configure parameters of --add-module in ./configure stage, but seems it does NOT work.

thanks for your help in advance.

.....................................

Answer (score 0):

## NGINX session_log

The directive `session_log` comes from the [http_session_log module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_session_log_module.html), in it's documentation the directive is mentioned:

```
Syntax:     

session_log name | off;

Default:    off;

Context:    http, server, location
```

> Enables the use of the specified session log. The special value off
> cancels the effect of the session_log directives inherited from the
> previous configuration level.

There are more directives like:

```
session_log_format name string ...;
session_log_zone path zone=name:size [format=format]
```

## NGINX full build and/or dynamic modules

There are "many" ways to build nginx with custom/"all" modules and you should be successful by studying how they do it, but you should already be able to "just enable" it

- https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-build-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts_597793
- https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/nginx-all-module
- https://gist.github.com/hermanbanken/96f0ff298c162a522ddbba44cad31081
- https://warlord0blog.wordpress.com/2022/11/08/nginx-container-with-custom-modules/
- https://github.com/tsuru/docker-nginx-with-modules ( custom modules .. )

Comment: thanks for your answer, but according to the official instruction, the session_log statement should be working at any place of "http, server, location" if it is successfully loaded. really don't know how to enable this module from the source package building.

Comment: could you plesae tell me how to download and add the module of "ngx_http_session_log_module"? seems this module is NOT originally included in the nginx-source-package.